# All of a sudden no new questions in search?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, search

This is probably only me, but I am only seeing questions from 1.5 hours ago or later.\

Screenshot:

[image: Are all newest questions very old?]

It isn't only for the Python tag either; any tag I look at on "Newest" has this issue.

Comment: Hmm, I'm seeing the same thing. That's strange.

Comment: @cigien No way there's no activity either, at least for python there would be at least 1-2 per minute

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I searched for [c++], and I'm *looking* at new questions at the same time :p

Comment: seems like an issue with [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpython%5d&searchOn=3). Accessing [the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=Newest) works fine

Comment: @cigien I feel bad for new users... imagine joining stack overflow and not getting a single answer, comment, upvote, downvote, edit, etc...

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried. As SurajRao mentions, filtering by tag is working, which is what a lot of users do (I think).

Comment: Interestingly, when putting the `answers:0` through the manual explicit filtering, this doesn't happen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true

Comment: This appears to be the same bug (or at least the same symptom) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261459/search-index-not-updating

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. No new results before 2 hours ago. [Try viewing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160050/auto-click-button-on-page-load). For some reason it does not [appear in search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A66160050). It was made 14 minutes ago.

Comment: We're question complete. All that is left to do is curating existing content ....

Comment: There was a report about this a few days ago, but it’s been deleted. It may have been [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360757/why-dont-i-get-the-last-questions-on-the-watched-tag) on MSE.

Comment: Note that the latest question IDs are close to 2^26 ~ 67 million

Comment: @0-1 What's the matter with 2^26? If it was 2^32 I would understand, but this? I don't get it.

Comment: @CATboardBETA I was curious to see if it was close to any power of 2. A recent question ID I just saw was 66161182. Whereas 2^26 is 67108864. The numbers differ by 1.4%. I think it may just be coincidence, though. Probably a similar issue [this question mentioned above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261459/search-index-not-updating)

Comment: This is in progress and should clear out shortly. Had some issues with re-indexing and started serving a stale cache. Apologies for any inconvenience and thanks so much for bringing it here so we could address it!

Comment: Looks like [it's fixed now?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22%22%20is%3aq)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yesterday a large backfill was executed across the `Posts` table network-wide. Updating the `Posts` table is usually fine - our search engine and the service that efficiently handles tag queries look at last updated time timestamps and perform a delta update of the things that changes.

Unfortunately the delta yesterday was on the order of 60m rows and the queries that are run to handle the delta really struggled. In many cases a full re-index would have been more efficient. This delta indexing had a bunch of effects:

- our indexing servers kept timing out running the queries causing unnecessary load on our SQL infrastructure
- Full text search and tag search got caught up trying to re-index the same thing constantly - at some points several servers were doing the same work

We temporarily switched off re-indexing to get things in a sane stable state then re-issued a full rebuild for Stack Overflow. That allowed other indexing servers to step in and delta re-index.

Re-indexing Stack Overflow takes 3.5 hours altogether and there’s some additional time while it propagates replicas around so we were back fully serving things by around 00:00 UTC.

To address this we’ll be adding some checks to see if we’ve reached a threshold whereby a delta no longer makes sense and use a full rebuild as well as some sanity checks to ensure the likes of Stack Overflow are actually indexing new questions within a timely fashion.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Just checking for side effects: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405143/why-is-getting-badges-really-slow

Comment: Afraid not @rene this only affected search, not anything badge related