# Badges are issued with a very long delay, up to 2 months

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I've heard of Stack Overflow being 2, 3, maybe 4 days slow, but why is THIS happening?

---

[image: Today: "Excavator" badge, edited first post that was inactive for 6 months. I edited Dec 16'20???]

---

<sup>For future readers: "Today" is February 12, 2021 in comparison to the edit date of December 16, 2020</sup>

I mean, I will be ok if Stack Overflow has some traffic and I am delayed for a week.  The problem here is that that edit was almost *2 months* ago.  Similar questions about badge updates being slow have been asked, but I've never seen any of them going this far.

The system that checks if I earned the Excavator badge probably should've noticed by now that I earned it. Maybe an <kbd>Update</kbd> button in user profiles could help verify that badges (and maybe other stuff) have been properly awarded, and if not give those badges to the user.

Does anyone else have any problems like this or some solutions?

Comment: You actually seem to have made that edit slightly less than 2 months ago. That still seems like quite a long time for the badge to get awarded.

Comment: You're not alone. https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator some more Excavators are awarded late.

Comment: Might be a side-effect of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405134/578411

Comment: As for me, I'm pretty sure I have enough for the Unsung Hero badge, but I still don't have it yet...

Comment: @rene: So you're suggesting that since it re-indexed Stack Overflow, it checked for the badges again and *finally* gave me the badge?

Comment: Yeah, that might be. I pinged Dean in a comment and left links to this post in chat for hopefully a dev to spot.

Comment: @rene: Yep, saw that.  Thanks for your help.  I was thinking Stack Overflow paused or something at the moment I edited and it didn't record it for badge counting, although I left it out of the post because that sounded silly.

Comment: Re-indexing would not have affected this. We had some other badge issues a few weeks back, will check in with our DBA on Monday

Comment: I had this happen to me on puzzling. However, I had already earned the badge months before. My count never changed and has been the same for months. Edit - I checked and the date of earning was not overridden.

Comment: badges, meh, you should have bigger things to worry about :)

Comment: Are you sure that you actually got that badge just now? A few days ago, I got hit by about 5 badge notifications for Code Review. When I clicked on one of the badges in my profile though, it said that I had actually been awarded it more than a year ago.

Comment: In Arqade, I complained I don't have the Curious badge displayed even if I already accomplished it. We really need to deal with badge-earning traffic in the whole network.

Comment: If any badges should be delivered late, this is one.

Comment: @DeanWard  I reported on MSE (Sept 2018) that some badges were not awarded, across the sites, but nothing came of it https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315480/282094 - I had hoped that the annual recalculation (and other synchronization events) would pick up the strays, but still a couple appear to be lost. --- It would be great if we could get a recount, even if it runs slowly at low priority; and takes many weeks to eventually get every number (badge, rep, etc.) exact.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 For the unsung hero, you need at least 40 *accepted* answers. You now have 25 on the main site. The exact criterium is, that *more* than 25% of your *accepted* answers must be zero-scored, and the 0-scored accepted answers must be *more* than 10 (at least 11).

Comment: @M-Chen-3 The not accepted, community wiki or deleted answers don't count (neither in the total and in the 25%). To get the unsung hero, best if you answer otherways crap questions of rep 1 users, *without fixing them*. So you try to ensure a low visit count ( -> your answer has little chance to be voted up), and the rep 1 users can not yet vote your answer up beside the accept.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica  Your math is off. 100% is more than 25%. So if they have 11 zero-scored accepted Answers and no other accepted Answers, they have more than 10 and more than 25%. Also, one can check out the progress at [How Unsung am I?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)- Just enter in your userid.

Comment: @Scratte My math is correct, at least into one direction, proof [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1357174). I can not see exactly what do you disagree. I wrote [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1357964) query to give more exact details about the unsungedness of a single user.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I know, and according to the Unsung Hero Stack Exchange query, I have more than 25% at 0 votes and accepted.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 You have 29 accepted, non-cw answers ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A13736952+isaccepted%3A1+wiki%3A0)), among them 9 is 0-scored ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A13736952+isaccepted%3A1+wiki%3A0+score%3A0)). This does not fulfill the first criteria (you need at least 11).

Comment: @M-Chen-3 However, your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65227043/1783163) answer imho clearly deserves an up, so you got it. One of your [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A13736952+isaccepted%3A1+wiki%3A0+score%3A1..1) answers might deserve a down, but I have no hearth to look for answers to vote them down. At least you are a step closer. :-)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica You do not need "40 accepted answers" to get the badge. Just 11 accepted zero-scored Answers. Those just need to be more than 25% of all your accepted Answers. That's it. Your first query gives "0 rows returned in 37298 ms". Your second query seems to be off by one. M-Chen-3 has 10 (not 11) zero-scored accepted Answers and is therefore not eligible for the badge. (SEDE says 8, but that was the data from sunday)

Comment: @Scratte You are right that 40 answers are not needed (44 is coming from that having the minimal 11 zero scored answers, you can have at most 44 accepted answer total). My first query returns 0 results because there is no one in the system who should have got the badge but did not get it. SEDE shows the state at the last SEDE dump, this was nearly a week ago (and the next dump will happen in some hours). This is why I have given main site search links to him, these have only some minute delay.

Comment: @Scratte He has now 10 zero-scored answers, because I voted his [only -1 scored accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65227043/1783163) up (because it obviously deserved it). Finally, if you take part in others' discussion, it would be highly useful to at least read what they earlier wrote to each other. Making me to replay myself poisons the whole thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be resolved.

There is a query that is used to identify users who qualify for the Excavator badge that has been silently timing out for several months, which resulted in the badges being awarded sporadically. I rewrote the query and it now executes in 10 seconds versus the minute plus which resulted in the time-out.

Comment: [Uhhhm, related](https://twitter.com/tarynpivots/status/1361410645262962692)  ... ?

Comment: @rene aye it is

Comment: *Sends badges for support and comfort ...*

Comment: So that query is causing Excavator badges to be awarded late because it times out and does nothing, and it doesn't give out any error, so no one noticed?  And because it did that for so long, the Excavator badge wasn't given out for a long time?  OK, that's probably the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @LakshyaRaj There was a generic error message in the logs, but nothing specifically said it was a SQL issue which is partly why I didn't see it. Yes, the query was timing out which meant the badge couldn't be awarded on a regular basis. The query has been fixed and the badge should now be awarded as expected on a daily basis.

Comment: OK, thanks!  Good thing most likely no one will have this problem anymore!